# App Engine: Is there a good general-purpose tool for caching datastore objects?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm looking at writing a super-class for all my Google App Engine datastore classes that looks something like this:

```
class MemcacheMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def cache_get_by_id(cls, id, parent=None):
        if memcache.has_key(...):
            ...
    ...

class MyEntity(db.Model, MemcacheMixin):
    ...

obj = MyEntity.cache_get_by_id(...)
```

The idea being that I'll almost always want to cache datastore objects, and I don't want to repeat myself. I assume someone must have already addressed this need and written a general-purpose tool for caching this stuff that integrates nicely into how the datastore classes work.

But, I haven't found it. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[NDB](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/) (the new datastore library developer by Guido and included in the App Engine 1.6.1 SDK ) has builtin (memcache and memory) caching facilites.

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache) for more details.

Comment: Now if it supported fulltext indexing.

Comment: @Ken take a look at the Search API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably looking for is a memoization decorator. Here's a good, simple example:

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-afterburner/source/browse/trunk/python/src/afterburner/experimental/memoize.py

Also related is the recommendation to cache the protocol buffer rather than the model instance, for performance:

http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching

Comment: Memoization looks very nice, but the one thing it's missing is updates. When an entity is updated, nothing invalidates the cache, unless you do that by hand.

Comment: @Ken "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things"

Comment: [@Nick @Ken] “There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.”